# Keras: fit_generator() feeding text in batches to the model

Tags: python, keras, generator, tf.keras

I'm new to the `fit_generator()` function and since my data is too big to fit into RAM, I figured to solve it via a generator.

Now, I do have a folder which contains each sample as a separate file. Each file is a `.npy` array, which I first need to pad to a certain length, so each numpy array becomes of size `(1000,600)`. I also have a file which contains my binary-labels (0,1).

So what I do not understand is, does keras `fit_generator()` wants a single sample at each time (sample,label) and creates the batches itself *or* do I have to create a batch first, which I then feed to the `fit_generator()`?

In my case, a single sample, namely a text, is of size `(1000,600)` and a batch of 50 samples should become `(50,1000,600)`.

Also, how do I ensure that each time a new batch of samples is fed to my model?

Until now my generator looks like:

```
def My_generator(features, labels, batch_size):
    ## features are names of each file stored in a np.array
    ## labels are binary and stored as np.array
    # array = []
    path = 'path_from_which_file_are_loaded/'

    while True:    ## endless loop
        for index in range(batch_size):
            batch_label = labels[index]
            batch_feature_names = features[index]
            name = batch_feature_names[0]

            # load single file
            single_file = np.load(os.path.join(path,name))

            ## create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels
            batch_features = np.zeros((1000,600))

            # pad loaded arrays to same length        
            shape = np.shape(single_file)
            batch_features[:shape[0],:shape[1]] = single_file ## pads np array to shape 1000,768
            #array.append(batch_features)

            yield (batch_features, batch_label)
```

For example, I just have 1000 files. I load them 50 at a time as one batch and feed it to fit_generator().
Each time I want to show the model a new batch of samples till the end of an epoch - which is in this case after 20 batches. How do I do that? I assume `steps_per_epoch` is in this case equal to 20?